# Searching user in LDAP

Tags: java, search, active-directory, directory, ldap

I am new to LDAP and trying to write a query to authenticate a user .The root in LDAP is 
dc=home, dc=alpha, dc=com.
There are many groups and users present under dc=home.It is a very deep tree with multiple nested
groups and users.I have to use

```
DirContext(InitialDirContext).search()
```

api to search the user.
I read the specification of

```
public NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> search(String name,String filter,SearchControls cons)
```

However i could not find whether it looks for the user recursively inside the specified root,or
does it just searche for the first level users or groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE` to do it recursively or `ONELEVEL_SCOPE` for just that level.

```
    ctx = getContext();
    SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
    constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    result = ctx.search(searchPath, searchFilter, constraints);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the depth behaviour you want in the `SearchControls` object: current object, one level lower, or entire subtree.